# CubicSpline of an ellipse in python

Tags: python, spline, ellipse

I want to calculate a CubicSpline in python for an ellipse with offset from the origin. As you can see in the minimal example below, the spline starts to oscillate enormously at zero. If the ellipse is completely in the positive area with respect to the x-axis, there are no longer any meaningful points in the spline.

If the ellipse is centered around the origin (or if you simulate a circle around the origin) then the spline gives very good results.

Is that because of the way my points are distributed, or is that a fundamental problem with the spline?

Thank you for the answers!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
scipy.interpolate import CubicSpline

#Testdata
data = np.array([
[-3.141592192012077, 0.30205445187957924],
[-1.6969620340898586, 1.8136860175700196],
[-1.573585940152737, 3.5131096569590583],
[-1.5029864212619968, 5.072527893977054],
[-1.4434392105234002, 6.423416553696333],
[-1.3856933107601075, 7.5149970049171095],
[-1.3258911015385528, 8.312549924569765],
[-1.2614361054146255, 8.798174980393007],
[-1.189701344815578, 8.97139931508294],
[-1.1072516626434445, 8.849836484875423],
[-1.0091064106665608, 8.470628997535261],
[-0.8879693573952719, 7.893580743103043],
[-0.7337833990427822, 7.206620069704828],
[-0.5351347437911634, 6.5321053268385025],
[-0.28611217587166543, 6.02419881159348],
[6.243187829294816e-08, 5.832752742349026],
[0.2861122907617031, 6.024199581785923],
[0.5351348008538365, 6.532105108830846],
[0.7337832165192042, 7.206619851628168],
[0.8879692937373075, 7.8935800741551185],
[1.0091064606652143, 8.470628836975099],
[1.1072515444460889, 8.849836055333858],
[1.1897014072231378, 8.971398596673133],
[1.261436158495886, 8.798175260204314],
[1.3258912263277856, 8.312548376446111],
[1.3856934473863394, 7.51499574282783],
[1.443438748468713, 6.423415256179228],
[1.502986111758742, 5.072526810729886],
[1.5735849232863501, 3.5131061275428577],
[1.6969618813128031, 1.8136860113166227],
[3.141593115167509, 0.30205445187957924]])

#Create Spline
cs = CubicSpline(data[:][:,0], data[:][:,1], bc_type='periodic')
xs = np.linspace(np.deg2rad(0), np.deg2rad(360), 300)

#Testdata to cartesian
point_x_y = np.zeros((31,2))
for p in range(0, 31):
    point_x_y[p][0] = data[p][1] * np.cos(data[p][0])
    point_x_y[p][1] = data[p][1] * np.sin(data[p][0])

#Splinedata to cartesian
spline_x_y = np.zeros((300,2))
for p in range(0, 300):
    spline_x_y[p][0] = cs(xs[p]) * np.cos(xs[p])
    spline_x_y[p][1] = cs(xs[p]) * np.sin(xs[p])


#Plot
fig1 = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot()
for p in range(0, 31):
    plt.plot(point_x_y[p][0], point_x_y[p][1], 'r+')

for p in range(0, 300):
    plt.plot(spline_x_y[p][0], spline_x_y[p][1], 'b+') 

plt.grid(color='k', linestyle='--', linewidth=0.5)
ax1.set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()
```